# CakePHP 3: how to get all associations of a table?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

That's the var_dump() of my table object:

```
object(App\Model\Table\BairrosTable)[117]
  public 'registryAlias' => string 'Bairros' (length=7)
  public 'table' => string 'bairros' (length=7)
  public 'alias' => string 'Bairros' (length=7)
  public 'entityClass' => string 'App\Model\Entity\Bairro' (length=23)
  public 'associations' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'regioes' (length=7)
      1 => string 'cidades' (length=7)
      2 => string 'clientes' (length=8)
      3 => string 'areas' (length=5)
  public 'behaviors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'defaultConnection' => string 'default' (length=7)
  public 'connectionName' => string 'default' (length=7)
```

I want to get just the array of the property associations, but if I try `$this->_table()->associations()`, I got an object with the itens on a protected variable:

```
object(Cake\ORM\AssociationCollection)[205]
  protected '_items' => 
    array (size=4)
      'regioes' => 
        object(Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo)[206]
          protected '_validStrategies' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected '_name' => string 'Regioes' (length=7)
          protected '_className' => null
          protected '_bindingKey' => null
          protected '_foreignKey' => string 'regiao_id' (length=9)
          protected '_conditions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_dependent' => boolean false
          protected '_cascadeCallbacks' => boolean false
          protected '_sourceTable' => 
            object(App\Model\Table\BairrosTable)[117]
              ...
          protected '_targetTable' => null
          protected '_joinType' => string 'INNER' (length=5)
          protected '_propertyName' => null
          protected '_strategy' => string 'join' (length=4)
          protected '_finder' => string 'all' (length=3)
          protected '_tableLocator' => null
      'cidades' => 
        object(Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo)[193]
          protected '_validStrategies' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected '_name' => string 'Cidades' (length=7)
          protected '_className' => null
          protected '_bindingKey' => null
          protected '_foreignKey' => string 'cidade_id' (length=9)
          protected '_conditions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_dependent' => boolean false
          protected '_cascadeCallbacks' => boolean false
          protected '_sourceTable' => 
            object(App\Model\Table\BairrosTable)[117]
              ...
          protected '_targetTable' => null
          protected '_joinType' => string 'INNER' (length=5)
          protected '_propertyName' => null
          protected '_strategy' => string 'join' (length=4)
          protected '_finder' => string 'all' (length=3)
          protected '_tableLocator' => null
      'clientes' => 
        object(Cake\ORM\Association\HasMany)[200]
          protected '_joinType' => string 'INNER' (length=5)
          protected '_strategy' => string 'select' (length=6)
          protected '_validStrategies' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected '_saveStrategy' => string 'append' (length=6)
          protected '_name' => string 'Clientes' (length=8)
          protected '_className' => null
          protected '_bindingKey' => null
          protected '_foreignKey' => string 'bairro_id' (length=9)
          protected '_conditions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_dependent' => boolean false
          protected '_cascadeCallbacks' => boolean false
          protected '_sourceTable' => 
            object(App\Model\Table\BairrosTable)[117]
              ...
          protected '_targetTable' => null
          protected '_propertyName' => null
          protected '_finder' => string 'all' (length=3)
          protected '_tableLocator' => null
          protected '_sort' => null
      'areas' => 
        object(Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany)[199]
          protected '_joinType' => string 'INNER' (length=5)
          protected '_strategy' => string 'select' (length=6)
          protected '_junctionTable' => null
          protected '_junctionTableName' => string 'areas_bairros' (length=13)
          protected '_junctionAssociationName' => null
          protected '_junctionProperty' => string '_joinData' (length=9)
          protected '_saveStrategy' => string 'replace' (length=7)
          protected '_targetForeignKey' => string 'area_id' (length=7)
          protected '_through' => null
          protected '_validStrategies' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected '_dependent' => boolean true
          protected '_targetConditions' => null
          protected '_junctionConditions' => null
          protected '_name' => string 'Areas' (length=5)
          protected '_className' => null
          protected '_bindingKey' => null
          protected '_foreignKey' => string 'bairro_id' (length=9)
          protected '_conditions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_cascadeCallbacks' => boolean false
          protected '_sourceTable' => 
            object(App\Model\Table\BairrosTable)[117]
              ...
          protected '_targetTable' => null
          protected '_propertyName' => null
          protected '_finder' => string 'all' (length=3)
          protected '_tableLocator' => null
          protected '_sort' => null
```

So, how do I get an array with all associations of a table?

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The `$this->_table()->associations()` is a `\Cake\ORM\AssociationCollection` object. So I use the [keys()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.AssociationCollection.html#_keys) method to get the array of associations.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3: [`getAssociation()`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.9/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#getAssociation)

```
$articlesTable = \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$association = $articlesTable->getAssociation('Tags')
```